# How to store a result of SQL query as String in python

Tags: robotframework, python-3.8, database-testing

I am using Robot framework in python and I am running below query:

```
${queryResults1}=  query  select count(*) from table
```

It gives me below result:

```
${queryResults2} = [(91,)]
```

How to convert above result as String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response format is a list of tuples - as can also be seen by the sample you've pasted. Thus get the 1st column of the first row (in python/Robot Framework the lists are 0-based), and pass that to `Convert To String`:

```
${the value as string}=    Convert To String    ${queryResults1[0][0]}
```